# ASP INLINE dropdownlist box in Gridview Edit Template

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to code a dropdownlist box into the edit template of a gridview. I have all that working. What I can't figure out is how to get the value from the dropdownlist box back to the Gridview so the Update button will post back.

I need to do this with ASP inline code, not a code behind page. I have converted the field in the gridview to a Templatefield.

Here is what I have so far but I keep changing to try other things....

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vehicle ID" SortExpression="tractorID"> 
 <EditItemTemplate> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server"  Width="70px" DataValueField="Value" 
                      SelectedValue='<%# Bind("tractorID") %>' DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  /> 
 </EditItemTemplate> 
 <ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tractorID") %>'></asp:Label> 
 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the correct code to get the job done. I was not able to figure out an INLINE solution and had to add this to the RowDataBound event.

```
' gets value of originally loaded record.
Dim vehID = row.Field(Of Integer)("tractorID") 
'  finds the dropdownlist to add the value to.
Dim tractorDDL As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("DropDownlist7"), DropDownList)
' Adds the value to the ddl
tractorDDL.Items.Add(vehID )      '  Adds value of the original record
```

Works flawlessly.